# Makefile says target is empty but it shouldn't be

Tags: makefile

I am trying to have a Makefile which is able to use different instances of `g++` based on whether I give along a certain target or not. So: If I run `make home` I want `CC` to be the `g++` executable in `/usr/bin`, and otherwise in some long path `<longpath>/bin`.
So I tried checking for my target:

```
ifeq ("$(TARGET)", "home")
    GCCPATH = /usr
    HSPARG = home
endif

$(info "$(TARGET)")
$(info "$@")

GCCPATH ?= <longpath>
CC = $(GCCPATH)/bin/g++
GCCLIBPATH = $(GCCPATH)/lib64
```

However, the outcome of this is:

```
$ make home
""
""
<further build information>
```

and `GCCPATH` is in all occasions equal to `<longpath>`.

Now my questions are:
1. What do I do wrong?
2. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `make home` doesn't set `TARGET` to `home`. So you have to execute `make TARGET='home'` to set it.

Secondly, `make` cares about spaces, including spaces after commas. So when you wrote `ifeq ("$(TARGET)", "home")`, `make` didn't toss away the space after the comma like you might have expected. So what `make` ended up comparing was "home" and " home".
You can see this by running `make TARGET=' home'` and seeing what you get. Remove that space and you'll fix the problem.

That said all your quoting isn't doing anything for `make` either. It doesn't generally care. Quotes are just literal characters to make in almost all places (except in `ifeq "arg1" "arg2"` cases, etc. and maybe one or two other places but I can't think of any offhand), so you don't need them in the calls to `$(info)` or even in your `ifeq` test since you are using the `ifeq (arg1,arg2)` version.